# Accessing array / scope of variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, scope

I am attempting to populate an array and use it later. I am getting "undefined" result when I try accessing objects at indexes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte"];

  var cb = '?client_id=5j0r5b7qb7kro03fvka3o8kbq262wwm&callback=?';
  var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
  var result = {};


  streamers.forEach(function(stream)
  {
    $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + stream + cb).success(function(data)
    {
        var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
        result.push(stream + " - " + streaming);
    });
  });

  alert(result[0]);
  alert(result[1]);
  alert(result[2]);
});
```

Comment: JSON functions are usually `asynchronous` which means that your array is being built after the main block of code is finished.

Comment: [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is asynchronous

Comment: Related to [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but there is probably a better duplicate somewhere for handling asynchronous operations in loops.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196 for an explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a `callback`, as your getting something for the server mostly happens in `asynchronous` processes, which mean that the code continues executing and only adds something to the array when something is returned. You want the script to only alert things when it completed a task, which is why we call it a call back, as it will *call* the passed function *back* (aka when it's done).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte"];

  var cb = '?client_id=5j0r5b7qb7kro03fvka3o8kbq262wwm&callback=?';
  var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
  // This should be initialised as an array, not an object!
  var result = [];
  
  function callback(){
    // I add this line to reduce the amount of alerts
    if(result.length !== 3) return;
    alert(result[0]);
    alert(result[1]);
    alert(result[2]);
  }


  streamers.forEach(function(stream){
    $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + stream + cb).success(function(data){
        var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
        result.push(stream + " - " + streaming);
        callback();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah yes indeed! My bad.

Comment: Also I would use the success to do the next call

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah you could, but for the purposes of this example it's not necessary. It would be better practise, but since I'm checking for the length it makes no difference in the end result.

Comment: I agree with @somethinghere - When you come to work on the results, it would be better to change the way this works. But for now it answers the question about viewing the data. Although I think my answer is better :P

Comment: @AdrianLynch I like your answer and upvoted it as well - its better at explaining asynchronous imho.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous.

Your alerts are running before you have data in the array.

To view the data when it's available, move the alerts (or better yet, console.logs) up into the success callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte"];
    var cb = '?client_id=5j0r5b7qb7kro03fvka3o8kbq262wwm&callback=?';
    var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
    var result = {};

    streamers.forEach(function(stream) {
        $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + stream + cb).success(function(data) {
            var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
            result.push(stream + " - " + streaming);
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Moving from looking at the results to using the results, you'll want to break things up a bit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte"];
    var cb = '?client_id=5j0r5b7qb7kro03fvka3o8kbq262wwm&callback=?';
    var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
    var result = {};

    var getStreams = streams.map(function (stream) {
        return $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + stream + cb).success(function(data) {
            var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
            result.push(stream + " - " + streaming);
            console.log(result);
        });
    });

    var onResultsSuccess = function (results) {
        console.log("I have all my streams, let's take a look at them:", results);
    };

    var onResultsFail = function () {
        console.log("Something's up!", arguments);
    };

    $.when(getStreams).then(onResultsSuccess, onResultsFail);

});
```

Untested so assume it's pseudo!

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing `result` **before** the `$.getJSON` callbacks have been executed. Many questions like this have been answered already, see [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196) for an explanation of the problem.

You should make use of the fact that all Ajax methods return [promises/deferred objects](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/) and use [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait for all of them to complete:

```
var deferreds = streamers.map(function(stream) {
  return $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + stream + cb).then(function(data) {
    var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
    return stream + " - " + streaming;
  });
});

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Even better but harder to understand promises than just wait for the result to be filled

Answer (score 0):

Not only should you defer the alert to after the calls, you should not loop Ajax externally..

Here is what I would suggest

```
function getStream() {
   if (result.length >= streamers.length) return;
   var stream = streamers[result.length];
   $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + stream + cb).success(function(data){
     var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
     result.push(stream + " - " + streaming);
     getStream();
   });
}
var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "GeoffStorbeck", "terakilobyte"];
var cb = '?client_id=5j0r5b7qb7kro03fvka3o8kbq262wwm&callback=?';
var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
// This should be initialised as an array, not an object!
var result = [];
$(function() {
  getStream();      
});
```